# not allowed to read the swagger of a microservice from the gateway

Tags: swagger, jhipster, spring-cloud, swagger-ui, jhipster-gateway

the gateway was generated by jhipster 7.0.1, and to that I added the dependency
"springfox-boot-starter" for io.springfox.

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
     <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
     <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
     <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
     <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Being in the ui i can see the gateway documentation and i can also see the microservices in my architecture but when i try to click on a microservice i get the following error

Failed to load API definition.

Fetch error
Unauthorized http://<url>/services/<servicename>/v3/api-docs

Comment: Why did you add the dependency "springfox-boot-starter"? Swagger-ui in gateway is supposed to work out of the box

Comment: originally i was looking for swagger on the link /swagger-ui.html with the default configuration of jhipster but i had a 401 error. so i read a tutorial on how to add swagger in springboot it's a recommendation i got

Answer (score 0):

I was able to have a solution to my problem, the trick is that at the gateway level to route the request asks for the token and when it does not see it, it returns an exception. so what I did is instead of returning an exception, it returns an empty test and everything passes very well